# I can't set a new variable on mysql

Tags: mysql, apache

I want to increase  `max_allowed_packet` variable on my server and I don't know why, when I add the sentence in `/etc/my.cnf`, it doesn't work!! This is the line I added:

```
max_allowed_packet=62M
```

But when I check the current value through `mysqladmin variables`, it shows 10M!! I've even restarted my server! And nothing happens!

What happens here?

Comment: which OS you are in ?

Comment: Under what heading did you the line? It should be under [mysqld]

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I'm using centos 6.5

@dwjv I added directly `max_allowed_packet=62M` into `/etc/my.cnf` and I restarted mysqld.

Comment: /etc/my.cnf needs to have headers in it. See this example: http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-configuration-file-sample

Comment: @dwjv Thank you!! That was a really stupid mistake! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [settings file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) will normally have several sections (what MySQL calls *groups*). You're possibly disregarding that fact:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
```